# Rewrite engine not working using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite url using htaccess but it's saying 404.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z0-9])$  product1.php?pid=$1
```

It's not opening product1.php file.

Comment: _"It's not opening profile1.php file"_ - and why should it, when you wrote `product1.php` instead.

Comment: Sorry by mistake i wrote profile but still i am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your htaccess file and your product1.php file are in same folder. If not that it will give 404 errors.

If they are not present in same folder then you need to complete relative path from the path where your htaccess file is present like: eg: Let's say we have folder structure like:

```
/root/.htaccess
/root/singh/test/product1.php
```

So have your rules in following manner then:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^p/([a-z0-9])$  singh/test/product1.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also apart from these put `NC` and `L` flags too in your rules to do case sensitive matching and making this condition's last rule here.

Comment: No my both file are in same folder but i have another htaccess file inside a folder should i show you that

Comment: @vivekmodi, ok, please do share all these details in your question, thank you.